# du reports different sizes on same directory

Tags: linux

Why does du produce a different size for the directory?

```
/tmp $ cd test_dir/
/tmp/test_dir $ dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=1024k count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4194304 bytes (4.2 MB, 4.0 MiB) copied, 0.00513522 s, 817 MB/s
/tmp/test_dir $ cd ..
/tmp $ du -b test_dir/*
4194304 test_dir/zero
/tmp $ du -b test_dir
4194322 test_dir
```

Comment: The directory itself apparently adds to the apparent size. Is the filesystem Btrfs?

Comment: No, its not Brtfs. Its ext4

Comment: it kinda makes sense that when you weight what is in the bucket, and then weigh the bucket itself, that the second measurement would include the weight of the bucket, but the first would not.

Comment: You think its counting the directory also? What is the weight of that?

Comment: 18 bytes apparently. a directory is just a special file that contains an array of child file names, and their inode numbers. so unless you are weighing the inodes too (which would be your blocksize), it comes down to how many and how long those filenames are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory exists in the file system, and takes up space. You can see how much by using `stat`

```
$ stat test_dir
  File: test_dir/
  Size: 60              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with [commit 110bcd28386b1f47a4cd876098acb708fdcbbb25](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=110bcd28386b1f47a4cd876098acb708fdcbbb25) `du`  with `--apparent-size` (which `-b` implies) should no longer count the space used by directories and the above should go away.